# How to set the minimum date in achartengine graph

Tags: achartengine

Hi in my app I made this graph !I´ve set renderer.setXAxisMin(0) but the first label of x axis is always hidden even if I try to use negative values the label do not appear. Thanks in advance

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Izt.png)

[image]

My code :

```
                            mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 30, 25, 20, 45 });
            mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
            // SET THE BACKGROUND COLOR
            getUnits(units);
            mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#339999"));

            mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(TEXT_SIZE_HDPI);
            mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(TEXT_SIZE_HDPI);
            mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(16);

            // mRenderer.setPointSize(TEXT_SIZE_HDPI);
            // mRenderer.setXTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.date));
            mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
            mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.WHITE);

            // mRenderer.setYTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.weight));
            mRenderer.setFitLegend(true);
            mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.parseColor("#339999"));
            mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
            mRenderer.setScale(1);
                            mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
            mRenderer.setInScroll(true);

            mRenderer.setShowGridY(false);

            mRenderer.setAntialiasing(true);
            mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
            mRenderer.setShowAxes(false);
            mRenderer.setShowGrid(false);
```

Comment: renderer.setXAxisMin(-1)

Comment: I´ve made that change and it just increase the space the label is still hidden

Comment: The error was when I add the xtextlabel :  `code`                         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, data[i]);
   }